# fo:external-graphic src="data:image/png;base64, ..." as attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a sniplet in my xslt like:

```
    <fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic src="data:image/png;base64, //base64 code//" />
    </fo:block>
```

Not to clutter my main stylesheet, i have created another xslt that have the base64 image as parameter like:

```
     <xsl:param name="logo">data:image/png;base64, //base64 code//</xsl:param>
```

If i change my main stylesheet to:

```
    .
    .
    <xsl:include href="image.xsl" />
    .
    .
    <fo:block>
    <fo:external-graphic>
    <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="$logo" /></xsl:attribute>
    </fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:block>
```

1st i get a heap-size error and after using -Xmx4096m i get a parse error.. When i have the base64 image embedded in the main stylesheet, i don't need the 4gb heap and the pdf i make have the image as intented.

Using Apache FOP 1.1 and sorry for my english, not my main language..

Comment: What is the parse error you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to use an attribute value template, I think. Use `{` and `}` to indicate that `$logo` is not a literal value, but a variable or parameter.

```
<fo:external-graphic src="{$logo}" />
```

Like this it is even more concise, since you do not have to type `xsl:value-of`.

Otherwise, `$logo` is stored as literal text content. Read about attribute value templates [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).

---

To illustrate this:

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:param name="logo">data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QNaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADQEPAAIAAAAGAAAAqgEQ</xsl:param>

      <fo:external-graphic src="{$logo}"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fo:external-graphic xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QNaRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgADQEPAAIAAAAGAAAAqgEQ"/>
```

Comment: @FastDuck Without seeing the whole stylesheet it is difficult to pinpoint the problem. Either try my updated suggestion or reveal more of your code.

Comment: I will try a more basic setup of this and if i can't get it to work, i will be back.. :)

Comment: @FastDuck Fine. Did you also try a tiny image as compared to a large image that could exceed the heap space?

Comment: I have no idea why or how.. I coded your example with a few changes so the parser wouldn't complain over formatting and missing elements, also changed your base64 string to something that actually is a picture?.. And voila.. Works.. Then i make a new stylesheet called image.xsl and put the parameter inside that and include it in the original.. Still works.. Exchange test image with the right image... App crash.. So, i think it have something to do with my base64 string or the length of it.. Have to look into that.. The solution you supplied, it works.. Thanks!

Comment: @FastDuck I think you have now accounted for a lot of factors that could be the culprit for your error. So, it might well be that the Base64 string is simply too extensive. Consider accepting the answer (mark the tick on the left) if you found it helpful.

Comment: Problem was my linebreaks.. The base64 string is valid but because i don't want a line thats 16kb long, i broke it in 200 char pieces.. If i use that "block" in the fo:external-graphics src="... directly, there is no problems.. But if i try that as a param, the application crashes.. So, my "images.xsl" stylesheet now only contains the pictures as one very long line.. Thanks again, was going nuts over this.. Answer accepted :)